# Xcode Code Signing Profile Names Don't Match

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, code-signing-entitlements

I'm confused about the names in the Code Signing section of Xcode.

[image: Code Sign Example]

Above I have a profile with my name and a number after it.  Example: John Smith (HW1234D).

If I go to ~/Library/Mobile Device/Provisioning Profiles none of the profiles in there have "HW1234D" as the ApplicationIdentifierPrefix.  Additionally, none of the profiles that have "iOS Team Provisioning Profile" as the name have "HW1234D" associated with it either.
Lastly if I look for profiles that were created or modified on Jan 2, 2013 none of them have "HW1234D" associated with it.

I have been looking all day at documentation and forums and I can't find any explanation of how to tell which profile is associated with which entry in the Code Sign section of Xcode.

Any ideas?  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that since Xcode manages the profiles that the profiles are just in memory and not in Library/Mobile Devices/Provisioning Profiles?  If so why does it keep old ones around?

Comment: Or maybe it's matching a number in the keychain?

Comment: OK.  One piece of the puzzle is that the "HW1234D" referred to above is actually the identifier of the cert in your keychain.  So I guess any profile in that cert will be covered by selecting that entry in Code Signing.